# Using Sybase ASE 12.5.4 and looking to list / concat string values

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

I want to create a query so that same values of column 1 and column 2 (tcbname and status) are grouped and column 3 (scope_name) lists all the scopes related to that status and tcb_name.

Below is my expected outcome

```
| TUVAmerica, inc | | E | |<all the scope_name values that match first two column>|
```

Comment: share your expected output

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin I have shared the expected result in my above question.

Comment: @HartCO I have tried so many things but nothing seems to be working at this point.

Comment: What is your MySQL version ?

Comment: Not exactly sure but its prior to 2008, it does not have Group_Concat nor Separator funtions

Comment: It does not look like that you are using MySQL. you might be using SQL Server !

Comment: I am using Sybase and Rapid Sql

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) and version?  the question has now been tagged as sybase-ase, but ASE never had versions based on years (ie, '2008' is not a valid ASE version) so I'm wondering if this is Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: @markp I am using ASE 12.5.4

Comment: @markp is there a way we could concat or LIST the string in one column in Sybase ASE 12.5.4?

Comment: @Aboyhasnoname for ASE 12.5.4 you're probably looking at having to write some T-SQL code (SQL batch; stored proc) to perform the concatenation; what do you plan on doing with the concatenated value ... send to client application? write to a table?

Comment: @markp I am pulling data out of Sybase to Servicenow. It requires data massaging so that's why I need to concatenate these values.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you need `group_concat()`

```
 select tcb_name ,status,
 group_concat(scope_name separator ',') as list_of_scope
 from your_table
 group by tcb_name,status
```